# Listening to sensors on Android Wear without Wear app

Tags: android, wear-os

for a project we're working on we have recently bought a Moto 360 Sport (2nd gen). I'm trying to find out if it's possible to listen to sensor events from the watch (like heart rate) in an Android app without writing a Wear app.

Basically the same as if you would listen to Location updates in your phone app but then for heart rate.

Is this even possible? Or do you always need a phone and companion wear app to get the watch sensor values? I haven't found any examples of this.

Answer (score 0):

You can access to fit's data with google account from your phone, I think. All data are synchronized with user's account.
Try to check GoogleAPIClient.

Comment: Do you know of an example that uses GoogleAPIClient without a corresponding Watch app? Seems every example I find they develop a phone app and a watch app at the same time and listen to the heart rate in the watch app and send it as a Message to the phone.

Answer (score 0):

As @Leo said, you can use Google Fit to know the heart rate. You can use the [Google Fit](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.apps.fitness) app on Android Wear devices as well as on other Android devices such as smartphones. You'll get the most out of Google Fit on your Android Wear watch when you pair it with your Android mobile phone or tablet. You can also use Fit only on your Android Wear watch. But you won't be able to see as much information or track as much of your activity.

Here's a [documentation](https://support.google.com/androidwear/answer/6056874?hl=en) on how to use Fit on Android Wear devices.

Comment: Perhaps I should clarify. :) I'm not looking for an app to see the heart rate. I'm looking for a way to listen to the heart rate stream in my Android app without writing an additional app to install on the Moto 360. Sorry for the confusion.